# Not able to run portractor tests in Chrome

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

I am not able to run my sample protractor tests in Chrome browser.

Here is my config.js file.

```
exports.config = {


    capabilities: {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "chromeOptions": {
        binary: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
        args: [],
        extensions: [],
    }
},
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  onPrepare: function() {
    var width = 1600;
    var height = 1200;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
},
  specs: ['C:/Users/Desktop/spec.js'],
};
```

Here is the spec.js file

```
describe('Guru99 Test', function() {
 it('should add a Name as GURU99', function() {
  browser.get('www.guru99.com');
    //expect(browser.getTitle().toEqual("Meet guru99"))
  element(by.xpath("//*[@href='/software-testing.html']")).click();
  var guru= element(by.xpath('html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/h3'));
  expect(guru.getText()).toEqual('Hello change GURU99!');
browser.driver.sleep(5000);
  });
});
```

It opens chrome, enters data; into URL, then enters HTML tags  likewise, for a moment and then opens URL but then does nothing...

How to solve this issue?

Chrome version - 58.0
Protractor version - 5.1.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you're running the latest version of `chromedriver`.

Comment: Yes, applied the command `webdriver-manager update` before running tests. Which I believe updated chromedriver.

Comment: can your try running it again after removing `browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);` from onPrepare method.

Comment: I get this code working by putting http before the URL and running selenium stand-alone

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by putting http://www.guru99.com, instead of www.guru99.com, and running selenium stand-alone.